# Особенности clearInterval и callback'ов в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, callback

Объясните поведение `clearInterval` в функции

```
var isEndGettingSettings = false;

function async_worker(callback) {
    var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
        if(isEndGettingSettings) {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
            callback();
        }
    }, 20);
}
```

При завершении ajax запроса флаг `isEndGettingSettings` становится true и любой обратный вызов (callback), посланный в функцию `async_worker` выполняется успешно и единожды, как и задумывалось. Но если строчки

```
clearInterval(intervalID);
callback();
```

Поменять местами, то `interval` не будет уничтожаться, а просто начнёт вызывать обратный вызов каждые 0,02 секунды. Почему у `clearInterval` такое странное поведение? Разве во втором случае не должен быть такой же результат, как и в первом?

Comment: понятно же, что дело в том, что происходит внутри функции `callback` - может Вы там опять вызываете `async_worker`, или возникает ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Поменял местами строки, интервал уничтожается

```js
var isEndGettingSettings = false;

document.querySelector('#start').onclick = function() {
  isEndGettingSettings = false;
  async_worker(function() { console.log('qeqqe'); });
};

document.querySelector('#true').onclick = function() {
  isEndGettingSettings = true;
};

function async_worker(callback) {
  intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    if(isEndGettingSettings) {
      callback();
      clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
  }, 20);
}
```

```html
<button id='start'>run worker</button>
<button id='true'>true</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался в чём проблема. Проблема в калбеке. В нём сторонним автором проводилась дополнительная проверка. Он добавил дополнительный интервал из-за него и сложилось впечатление, что функция не работает, как надо. Хотя, на самом деле виноват калбек.

Comment: только по-русски *колбэк*, калбек приобретает другой смысл :)